# Intellisense for csx in VisualStudio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, cs-script, csx

I am new in programming cs scripts (csx files).

But I have the problem that I do not have any intellisense. How can I get intellisense support in Visual Studio 2015 for it?

Answer (score 5):

## Cs Script (CS file) and Script Cs (CSX file)

#### Cs-Script


It is a scripting engine that exists for quite a long time and use plain C# syntax (extension are hidden in comments). It also uses its own scripting engine.

**There is an [Intellisense extension for CS Script](http://www.csscript.net/CSScriptVSX.html). However it states that it's for Visual Studio up to 2013 version, so maybe it is not compatible with 2015 version.**

#### Script CS

**... and CSI, Dotnet.Script and Nake**

They are scripting engines based on Roslyn engine (and Mono REPL Engine for some of them). The syntax is extended:

- No namespaces allowed
- No main class, main method entry point not needed
- Additional directives, like #load or #r to respectively load a script file and reference an assembly.
- Common used **`using`** are not needed (like `System` or the like)

Obviously providing intellisense for such extended syntax is more complex and **[Support by Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 is not complete](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/search?q=intellisense+csx&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93).**

**But it is available in Visual Studio Code through [Omnisharp](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-roslyn/pull/199).**

***Note for Resharper Users:***

*You have to disable intellisense of Resharper for all **Cs** files (as R# see them as C# but cannot handle intellisense for them) and of course specify *.csx files as skipped by code inspection.*